# How to swap MAAttachedWindow's view

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

How can I swap the view of my MAAttachedWindow with the window visible?

```
defaultViewController = [DefaultViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DefaultView" bundle:nil];

attachedWindow = [[MAAttachedWindow alloc] initWithView:[defaultViewController view]
                                                attachedToPoint:point 
                                                       inWindow:nil 
                                                         onSide:MAPositionBottom 
                                                     atDistance:25.0];
```

How would I swap in AnotherViewController's view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a good night's sleep, it took 5-minutes to figure this out!

```
NSViewController *vc = [[NSViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainView" 
                                                              bundle:nil];
view = vc.view;
[vc release];

// Setup firstViewController here, addSubview and set current = firstViewController.view

attachedWindow = [[MAAttachedWindow alloc] initWithView:view 
                                        attachedToPoint:pt 
                                               inWindow:nil 
                                                 onSide:MAPositionBottom 
                                             atDistance:5.0];
```

Then in my swap view method, simply:

```
-(void)swapView
{
    SecondViewController *secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondView" bundle:nil];

    // Resize our host view
    [view setFrameSize:secondViewController.view.frame.size];

    // Replace the current view
    [view replaceSubview:current with:secondViewController.view];

    // Resize our attachedWindow
    [attachedWindow setFrame:secondViewController.view.frame display:YES];

    [secondViewController release];
    [current release];
}
```